# I have a problem about using @ConditionalOnClass

Tags: spring-boot

Part of the code is as follows:

```
Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
@ConditionalOnClass({ RabbitTemplate.class, Channel.class })
@EnableConfigurationProperties(RabbitProperties.class)
@Import(RabbitAnnotationDrivenConfiguration.class)
public class RabbitAutoConfiguration
```

RabbitTemplate.class is not exists in springboot, but the project still can run success.

who can tell why?

Comment: Are you sure it does not exist?

Comment: I created the project and my pom.xml  dependencies as follows:           
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

Comment: the code in question  is not mine, it's  inside the  springboot project

Answer (score 0):

Because [`org.springframework.amqp:spring-rabbit` is](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/build.gradle#L209) **optional** ([gradle](https://blog.gradle.org/optional-dependencies)|[maven](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html)) dependency in `spring-boot-autoconfigure`, which *is* on your classpath (through `spring-boot-starter` *transitively*) .

Thus, you can use `RabbitAutoConfiguration` (in your code), but to use (/import/declare) `RabbitTemplate`, you have to add it to the classpath (=> i.e. enabling `RabbitAutoConfiguration`).

---

Some additional considerations:

- `@ConditionalOnClass` takes (preferably) a `Class<?>[]` element (optionally a `String[]`) ..lets assume the class is available.
- whereas `@ConditionalOnMissingClass` takes *only* `String[]` argument, and gives the opportunity to "mention" some (unavailable) classes, which don't have to be on the class path. ;)